# Connection strings & app settings in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-core, exception, connection-string

Haven't worked in .net core before and I am having some issues with the connection string.
I am trying to get the connection string in my controller like so

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
```

but I am getting an **'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'** in my controller. 
This is what my **appsettings.json** looks like

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(server)\\\\mssqllocaldb;Database=dbName;User ID=user;Password=123123"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the connection string directly in your controller, but you can inject the configuration and then you can access the connection string like this in your controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController (IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The use of ConfigurationManager assumes the presence of "App.config" in your project, not appsettings.json.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=(server)\\\\mssqllocaldb;Database=dbName;User ID=user;Password=123123" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

To use

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
```